# Local Merge Argument definition not found

Tags: terraform

I am attempting to merge my tfvars values into a locals block, but it appears the merge is not working. For example, I put the location value in the tfvars to null and based on the code, in that case, it should instead choose the location of the Resource Group. I get an error of "The argument location is required, but no definition was found." Makes me feel that the whole merge is not happening at all.

Similarly, the merge of the tags is not working.

Does the merge only work for values that don't exist in the tfvars or can it take existing values, run logic on them, and produce the output? Maybe my whole idea of the merge is wrong if it cannot do the latter.

Any help appreciated.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/merge): "If more than one given map or object defines the same key or attribute, then the one that is later in the argument sequence takes precedence."

```
##Data Source for Resource Groups
data "azurerm_resource_group" "resource_groups" {
  for_each = { for law in var.log_analytics_workspace : law.name => law }
  name     = each.value.resource_group_name
}

###LOCALS###
locals {
  laws = { for law in var.log_analytics_workspace : law.name => merge(
    {
      location                           = law.location != null ? law.location : data.azurerm_resource_group.resource_groups[law.name].location
      sku                                = coalesce(law.sku, "PerGB2018")
      retention_in_days                  = coalesce(law.retention_in_days, 30)
      daily_quota_gb                     = coalesce(law.daily_quota_gb, 1)
      internet_ingestion_enabled         = false
      internet_query_enabled             = false
      cmk_for_query_forced               = false
      reservation_capacity_in_gb_per_day = law.sku != "CapacityReservation" ? null : law.reservation_capacity_in_gb_per_day
      tags                               = merge(data.azurerm_resource_group.resource_groups[law.name].tags, law.tags)
    }, law)
  }
}



#Log Analytics Resource
resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "log_analytics_workspace" {
  for_each                           = local.laws
  name                               = each.value.name
  resource_group_name                = each.value.resource_group_name
  location                           = each.value.location
  sku                                = each.value.sku
  retention_in_days                  = each.value.retention_in_days
  daily_quota_gb                     = each.value.daily_quota_gb
  internet_ingestion_enabled         = each.value.internet_ingestion_enabled
  internet_query_enabled             = each.value.internet_query_enabled
  cmk_for_query_forced               = each.value.cmk_for_query_forced
  reservation_capacity_in_gb_per_day = each.value.reservation_capacity_in_gb_per_day
  tags                               = each.value.tags
}
```

```
log_analytics_workspace = [
  {
    name                               = "law-eastus-dev-01"
    resource_group_name                = "rg-eastus-dev-01"
    location                           = "eastus"
    sku                                = "PerGB2018"
    retention_in_days                  = 7
    daily_quota_gb                     = 1
    reservation_capacity_in_gb_per_day = 100
    tags = {
      law = "dev-east"
    }
  }
]
```

```
Changes to Outputs:
  + laws = {
      + law-eastus-dev-01 = {
          + cmk_for_query_forced               = false
          + daily_quota_gb                     = 1
          + internet_ingestion_enabled         = false
          + internet_query_enabled             = false
          + location                           = "eastus"
          + name                               = "law-eastus-dev-01"
          + reservation_capacity_in_gb_per_day = 100
          + resource_group_name                = "rg-eastus-dev-01"
          + retention_in_days                  = 7
          + sku                                = "PerGB2018"
          + tags                               = {
              + "law" = "dev-east"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add to the question what does `local.laws` variable look like after merge?

Comment: Output added above.

Comment: I was able to get it working by completely changing the inputs to a map (keyed from the name of the resource) and then reworking all the locals references to match that. Not that I wanted though. I should be able to keep it simple as a list(object).